# PDFsharp : How can i get rid of Adobe Reader when printing?

Tags: pdfsharp

When I print a pdf file with PDFsharp in c# with this code below

```
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = printDialog1.PrinterSettings;
            PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
            PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter(pdfFilename, printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);

            try
            {
                printer.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
```

, everything is fine while printing but one thing I don't like is AdobeReader pops up.
How can I close this pop-up by code?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The PdfFilePrinter class uses `Process.Start` to start Adobe Reader. You can play with the `ProcessStartInfo` options and maybe you can get the behavior you want (launch minimized or without a window at all etc.).

PDFsharp is open source and the PdfFilePrinter class is included in the source package. IIRC this class was developed in the days of Adobe Reader 5 or 6. Maybe Adobe Reader 10 or XI can do better with a slightly modified way of invoking them.

I don't have time to try this myself, but I would like to hear from you if you managed to improve your issue.

Or is the issue to close Adobe Reader after printing? That would be more difficult as you have to find out when Reader finished printing.

Comment: I would try your suggestion and let you know if i completed it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have tried using ProcessStartInfo but the result was the same . It can't be helped , however, i ignore this issue already. Thanks again for your suggestion.